# How can I display this rather unusual schedule is an easy to digest manner via PHP and a web language?

Tags: php, css, html

I'll do the best to explain this, but please ask clarifying questions as needed:

I basically have a schedule attempting to map out seven stages of an event, which occurs over a period of roughly a week.  This data is presently in timestamps which are difficult to read and hard to draw conclusions from, and I would like to present it visually some how.

Each stage has an estimated period of time in which it might occur, and these times can overlap with other stages because they are estimates (and in fact typically will).

In addition to the estimates, in certain stages I will sometimes know when part of the stage is known, with certainty, to be occurring.

The purpose of this map/schedule is to allow a user to look at the schedule and instantly recognize what periods of time stages are likely to occur, and what periods of time stages are definitely occurring.

How do I translate my timestamps into some sort of visual to convey this information?  Would HTML 5 be the way to go, and if so, in what manner?

Thank you for your input

Comment: Sounds like a question better suited to http://ux.stackexchange.com/ (at least the first part of it, the second part depends too much on the first part to be answerable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is hard to answer - so I will only try the part where you are asking on how to visualize the information.

I can recommend using the highchart library for any kind of statistical visualization.

http://www.highcharts.com/

You can find some demos here:

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/

It all works with Javascript and even in older browsers which is nice.

Comment: While those charts look amazing, and the library is great, I'm not sure how I would apply any of the charts to make it work for this scenario... did you have a thought with that?

Comment: Whoops, sorry, still getting the hang of stackoverflow I guess.  I should have tagged your name @Horen!

Comment: hmm, that's hard for me to say. if i understood your case correctly maybe a stacked column chart could work where every different colored stack stands for a certain stage and the y-axis would represent time?
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked On a side note: The author of an answer is always notified when somebody comments. So I saw your post but just didn't have time to answer :)